# Cannot convert decimal(4,2) to decimal(10,2)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have [this field in my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0a5.png)
I need to make it decimal(10,2), but when I tried to do it, [I receive an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y8iv.png).

Comment: I am so tired of people who post screen captures of text results. Isn't that _more_ work than just copy & paste the text? And it makes it harder for us to read your question.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I'm attacking you, when you're a newbie. But please understand I've seen _thousands_ of posts on Stack Overflow where screen captures were used when it would have been easier and clearer to just copy the text. I don't understand why this is so common. But please don't take my frustration personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`ALTER TABLE users MODIFY rate decimal(10,2);`